# Youtube IFrame API sometimes doesn't fire `onError` event

Tags: youtube-iframe-api

I encountered a problem when YT Iframe API doesn't trigger the `onError` event when the video is not available anymore (removed/unlisted/etc). Here is an example I use the API, everything according to the documentation:

```js
new window.YT.Player(this.domElementId, {
      height: '380',
      width: '560',
      playerVars: {
        enablejsapi: 1,
        version: 3,
        autohide: 1,
        autoplay: 1,
        color: 'red',
        theme: 'dark',
        iv_load_policy: 3,
        modestbranding: 1,
        rel: 0,
        showinfo: 0,
        cc_load_policy: 0
      },
      videoId,
      events: {
        onReady: this.playerReady.bind(this),
        onError: this.playerError.bind(this),
        onStateChange: this.handleStateChange.bind(this)
      }
    });
```

If you replace `videoId` with some id of a video that is not there anymore, it may sometimes trigger the `onError` event, but sometimes not. It seems to be very random.

Again, according to the documentation and my experience, it's supposed to trigger `onError` event with a code `150`, which stands for `can't embed this video in general`.

Any solutions for this issue?

Comment: I'm having the same issue on Firefox.

Comment: I am also seeing this. `onReady` runs just fine, but then I have no way to determine if video actually is ready until the user clicks play—which is too late for my use case.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround for this, which I also posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71094421/7347484). (Re-posting full workaround at the request of a reviewer.)

In my case, the `onError` callback would only fire if the player had completely loaded first, so try this:

- Remove the `autoplay` param from the `playerParams` object if you
  have it-- this causes the fix to fail.
- Add `loadByVideoId` (for
  autoplay) or `cueByVideoId` with the same video id to the `onReady`
  callback.

This will reload the current video as soon as the player is ready and the `onError` callback will fire as needed.

- [Here is a codesandbox demonstrating **the issue**.](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-youtube-demo-forked-wyenn?file=/src/App.js) Note that the
  error isn't added to the list until the "reset" button is clicked.
  (As of Feb 14, 2022, while the bug still exists.)
- [Here is a codesandbox demonstrating **the workaround**.](https://codesandbox.io/s/onerror-issue-workaround-xgjx7?file=/src/App.js) Notice the `onReady` callback, and the error populating on the list.

The `react-youtube` package in the sandbox is just a wrapper that takes care of boilerplate-- I implemented the same workaround into my codebase that did not utilize the package and the result is the same.