# YouTube Iframe API onError event does not fire in recent months

Tags: javascript, youtube-iframe-api

I'm pretty sure YouTube Iframe API "onError" event will fire in the past since I run a project based on this API. But recently "onError" event will not fire, even the simplest error.

This is a simple sample code based on official page( https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference ) and is workable:

```
<iframe id="existing-iframe-example"
        width="640" height="360"
        src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/M7lc1UVf-VE?enablejsapi=1"
        frameborder="0"
        style="border: solid 4px #37474F"
></iframe>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var tag = document.createElement('script');
  tag.id = 'iframe-demo';
  tag.src = 'https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api';
  var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

  var player;
  function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('existing-iframe-example', {
        events: {
          'onReady': onPlayerReady,
          'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange,
          'onError': onError
        }
    });
  }
  function onError(event) {
    console.log(event.data)
  }
  
  function onPlayerReady(event) {
    
  }

  function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    console.log(event.data);
  }
</script>
```

Once change the video id string "M7lc1UVf-VE" as a wrong one, such as "M7lc1UVf", it should fire "onError" event, but doesn't now.

According to official page guide: https://developers.google.com/youtube/players/support → "Google engineers monitor and answer questions with the youtube-iframe-api tag", hope Google engineers can see this post and fix the "onError" problems.

Comment: I am also seeing this when using an invalid id. `onReady` runs just fine, but then I have no way to determine if video actually is ready until the user clicks play—which is too late for my use case.

Comment: I've also noticed an issue in which onError doesn't fire. I have a player, which I replace the video id if a user clicks a button. If the selected id errors, it should fire onError, but this doesn't happen. It only happens if the initial video is errored. So, it appears on onError is only reacting to the initial loaded video, not if the video is changed to an errord id.

Comment: I am noticing the opposite behavior David. If anyone is seeing no errors firing on initial load, see my fix below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a workaround for this. I found that, at least in my case, the `onError` callback doesn't fire on initial load (when it's most needed!) but will fire after the rest of the player loads completely.

If you absolutely need the `onError` event to work, you can reload the video within a loaded player. Remove the `autoplay` param from the `playerParams` object-- this causes the hack to fail. Add `loadByVideoId` (for autoplay) or `cueByVideoId` with the same video id to the `onReady` callback.

This will reload the current video and the `onError` callback will fire if needed. Otherwise, there will be little to no noticeable effect--other than the video being briefly cued before it plays if `autoplay` is expected.

Let me know if you'd like more info-- hope that helps!

EDIT:

- [Here is a codesandbox demonstrating **the issue**.](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-youtube-demo-forked-wyenn?file=/src/App.js) Note that the
  error isn't added to the list until the "reset" button is clicked.
  (As of Feb 12, 2022, while the bug still exists.)
- [Here is a codesandbox demonstrating **the workaround** I found.](https://codesandbox.io/s/onerror-issue-workaround-xgjx7?file=/src/App.js) Notice the `onReady` callback, and the error populating on the list.

---

UPDATE:
I don't know when it happened-- the devs at Google never updated my issue-- but it looks like this bug may have been resolved. The first demo now lists the error code on load as expected. For anyone that implemented this workaround, you may be able to remove the hack now.

Comment: Thank for your efforts, Ned, with respect. I've tested & you're right, onError will fire only when "reload", not at the first time, which is very annoying.. Forcing to load video twice is not a pleasant way, but it seems the only way for now. Hope Google will fix it someday.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer, it solved my problem too.

Answer (score -1):

You need to load the page from a server (not local). Just change it to not load locally.

I was having the same issue, and realized that if I'm loading the page locally most error events wont raise. If I load the page from my azure server, the errors are correct.
Also, some videos will not work/load at all if the html is locally loaded.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29890840)